# Micronaut App from Docker cannot connect to database (Exception during pool initialization)

Tags: postgresql, docker, micronaut

Initial conditions:

1. Postgresql is a separate instance. 2) There is a micronaut application that implements the RestAPI functionality and receives information for its work from an external database.
   Application type:
2. Separate jar application - works
3. Micronaut native compile application - works
4. Regular docker application - does not work
5. Docker micronaut native compile application - does not work

To demonstrate the problem, I took the reference application of micronaut expert Sergio del Amo on github [micronaut-data-jdbc-graal](https://github.com/micronaut-graal-tests/micronaut-data-jdbc-graal/tree/1.3.x_postgres)

To reproduce, you can take this reference application and build a Docker image.

application.yml:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: example-jdbc
jackson:
  bean-introspection-module: true
---
datasources:
  default:
    url: 'jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:concrete_address}:${DB_PORT:5432}/pets'
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: xxxxxxx
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: POSTGRE
```

How to reproduce:
Create a docker image using any default method ./gradlew dockerBuild or ./gradlew dockerBuildNative

The image is generated using this method with a random name like "f466503c2b5f"

[image]
Starting the application via Docker: `docker run -p 8080:8080 024d6c8c1ab9`
We get an error:
[image]

If you use docker-compose the error is similar.
Example docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
#networks:
#  work-network:
#    driver: bridge
services:
  app:
    environment:
      DB_HOST: 192.168.1.72 # host postgres
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxx
      DB_PORT: 5432
    image: 10b46d5605fd
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
#    networks:
#      - work-network

14:28:54.980 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
14:29:06.051 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.HikariUrlDataSource.<init>(HikariUrlDataSource.java:35)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceFactory.dataSource(DatasourceFactory.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.$DatasourceFactory$DataSource0$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:161)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:867)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:852)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.SchemaGenerator.createSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:99)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.$SchemaGenerator$Definition.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.$SchemaGenerator$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2746)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1915)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:249)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3684)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:341)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:194)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:323)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:309)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:30)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:331)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:630)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
14:29:06.055 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.SchemaGenerator] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.
Path Taken: DataSource.dataSource(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.SchemaGenerator] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.
Path Taken: DataSource.dataSource(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1921)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:249)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3684)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:341)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:194)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:323)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:309)
    at example.Application.main(Application.java:30)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Message: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.
Path Taken: DataSource.dataSource(DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:867)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:852)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.SchemaGenerator.createSchema(SchemaGenerator.java:99)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.$SchemaGenerator$Definition.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.data.jdbc.config.$SchemaGenerator$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
    at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2746)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1915)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The connection attempt failed.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.HikariUrlDataSource.<init>(HikariUrlDataSource.java:35)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceFactory.dataSource(DatasourceFactory.java:66)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.$DatasourceFactory$DataSource0$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:161)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:331)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:630)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

However, a similar configuration works in SpringBoot.
This is the last obstacle to abandon SpringBoot and switch to Micronaut, since micronaut turned out to be much more efficient than SpringBoot (my humble opinion). Maybe some more fine-grained network settings for docker are needed?
Please help with advice.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution with network settings for Docker. You need to specify **network_mode: "host"**. Maybe this information will help someone (see below) For the SpringBoot bundle in the native code (GrailVM), I did not make such settings for the docker.

```
docker run --network="host" -p 8080:8080 024d6c8c1ab9

version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: ZSE4zse4
      DB_PORT: 5432
    image: 9bd5c8278710
#    ports:
#      - "8080:8080"
```